# Spring Security: how to get an authorized user in applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Sorry for my english. How to get an authorized user in applicationContext.xml

`Authentication` class:

```
public class Authentication {
    public Account getAccount(){
        return (Account) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }
}
```

And in file applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="Authentication" class="com.otv.util.Authentication">
</bean>

<bean id="CurrentAccount"
      factory-bean="Authentication"
      factory-method="getAccount"/>
```

But it is not working:

> Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'Principal' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public com.otv.model.entity.Account
>   com.otv.util.Authentication.getAccount()] threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]]

How can I get an authorized user in applicationContext.xml?

#### UPDATED

If I use as said holmis83. I get error:

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException:object references an unsaved transient 
>   instance - save the transient instance before flushing: 
>   com.otv.model.entity.Account

In applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="Authentication" class="com.otv.util.Authentication"/>

<bean id="CurrentAccount" factory-bean="Authentication" factory-method="getAccount" scope="request">
   <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>

<bean id="PostPaginatorDTO" class="com.otv.model.dto.paginator.PostPaginatorDTO" scope="request">
    <property name="account" ref="CurrentAccount" />
</bean>
```

`PostBean` class:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{PostPaginatorDTO}")
public PostPaginatorDTO paginatorDTO;

public List<Post> getEntityList() {

    entityList=getDao().findByPostPaginatorDTO(getPaginatorDTO());

    return entityList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to create a bean with another scope than default, which is singleton. Use `scope` attribute. If you want to use your scoped bean in a singleton bean, you better use a scoped proxy too.

```xml
<bean id="CurrentAccount" factory-bean="Authentication" factory-method="getAccount" scope="request">
  <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

Comment: @sergeyivanov Error looks slightly unrelated. Search for "TransientObjectException" or ask a new question maybe?